# HSQL, In-memory databases, Java and PHP question

Tags: java, php, caching, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I'm investigating options to create a database cache using HSQLDB in an in-memory mode. The idea is that the cache will be queried from a PHP application and the query will be passed to a Java application that runs the HSQLDB database.

Now, I've been thinking this through and I can't see any efficient way to pass the data from Java back to the PHP app. I know XML is an option, and so is JSON but i'm not sure if the additonal processing will be an overhead? Ideally I just want to pass an array of data back from the java to the php like what you would get with mysql_fetch_array or something.

I know it seems like a weird question, and probably seems completely illogical but i'm just exploring this option so please bare this in mind!

Comment: Did either of the answers help you?  If so, you might consider choosing one as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities are [Facebook's thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) and Google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).  Thirft is probably a better choice for you since support for [PHP in protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/pb4php/) is fairly limited.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Hessian (http://hessian.caucho.com/)
If performance is what you are after I think Hessian is at or near the top - though the binary mode in Thrift is no slouch.